# Как вставить в форму на WPF выделенную область из .exe приложения

Tags: c#, wpf, exe

**1) Есть окно на WPF:**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В пустою область необходимо вставить окно другого приложения.

**2) Есть окно другой программы:**

[image]

Красным выделена область, которую необходимо вставить в окно WPF.

**3) Каким образом можно получить следующий результат:**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Так же необходимо что бы вставленная область работала в real-time режиме, так как в этой программе будут обновляться важные данные.

Очень нужна помощь.

Comment: Смотрите WINAPI SetParent

Comment: Вы собрались Франкейнштейна запилить? :)

Comment: @nick_n_a, спасибо, посмотрю.

Comment: @AGS17, не совсем :) Задача объединить в один интерфейс несколько разных .exe приложений, для удобства управления. Управление другими приложениями я реализовал, с помощью TestStack.White. Осталась задача отобразить с другого приложения данные.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Получилось реализовать, как и советовал [nick_n_a](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/17974/nick-n-a) c помощью  WINAPI SetParent. Программа .exe отображается на форме WPF на DockPanel.

Код программы:

```
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    static extern IntPtr SetParent(IntPtr hWndChild, IntPtr hWndNewParent);

    [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern bool MoveWindow(IntPtr hWnd, int X, int Y, int nWidth, int nHeight, bool bRepaint);

    private Process pDocked;
    private IntPtr hWndOriginalParent;
    private IntPtr hWndDocked;
    public System.Windows.Forms.Panel pannel;

    private void MainWindow_Deactivated(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Topmost = true;
    }

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        pannel = new System.Windows.Forms.Panel();
         host.Child = pannel;
        dockIt("programm.exe");
    }
    private void dockIt(string utility)
    {
        if (hWndDocked != IntPtr.Zero) //don't do anything if there's already a window docked.
            return;

        pDocked = Process.Start(utility);
        while (hWndDocked == IntPtr.Zero)
        {
            pDocked.WaitForInputIdle(1000); //wait for the window to be ready for input;
            pDocked.Refresh();              //update process info
            if (pDocked.HasExited)
            {
                return; //abort if the process finished before we got a handle.
            }
            hWndDocked = pDocked.MainWindowHandle;  //cache the window handle
        }
        //Windows API call to change the parent of the target window.
        //It returns the hWnd of the window's parent prior to this call.
        hWndOriginalParent = SetParent(hWndDocked, pannel.Handle);

        //Wire up the event to keep the window sized to match the control
        SizeChanged += window_SizeChanged;
        //Perform an initial call to set the size.
        AlignToPannel();
    }

    private void AlignToPannel()
    {
        MoveWindow(hWndDocked, 0, 0, pannel.Width, pannel.Height, true);
    }

    void window_SizeChanged(object sender, SizeChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        AlignToPannel();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Думаю, вам нужно смотреть на [`HwndHost`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.interop.hwndhost(v=vs.110).aspx). Его наследником, например, является [`WinFormsHost`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.forms.integration.windowsformshost(v=vs.110).aspx), который позволяет встраивать WinForms контролы в WPF. Работающего кода дать не могу, но, например, в [**AvalonDock**](https://avalondock.codeplex.com/) при помощи `HwndHost` сделано отображение плавающих панелей. Панель существует в виде контрола WPF внутри окна, когда её вытаскивают в плавающую панель (то есть отдельное окно), внутри этого окна создаётся `HwndHost`, который отображает содержимое панели из основного окна. Сделано, насколько я понимаю это для того, чтобы не пересоздавать панель, и вроде бы такой же механизм используется в Visual Studio. На ваш случай более, чем похоже.